# Using .load with variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery, load

Made some 2 buttons on my blog so users can go the next or back trough posts. I think would be interesting to show the posts titles. It's a blogspot blog so I'm trying to use a variable to catch the URL's so I can use them with .load and target the post's title:

```
$(function(){
   var getlink = $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").attr("href");
   var gettitle = $('.entry').load(getlink+ "#this-post-title"); //this part won't work!
   $("<div id='next-title'>"+gettitle+"</div>").appendTo("a.blog-pager-newer-link");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a general logic issue.

```
$(function(){
      // set getlink equal to the value of the href attribute of the link
      var getlink = $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").attr("href");
      // set gettitle equal to the element with a class of entry
      var gettitle = $('.entry').load(getlink+ "#this-post-title"); //this part won't work!
      // create a new div that contains the toString of the gettitle object( [object Object] )
      $("<div id='next-title'>"+gettitle+"</div>").appendTo("a.blog-pager-newer-link");
});
```

What you actually want to do is load the contents of a url into the link.

```
$(function(){
      // set getlink equal to the value of the href attribute of the link
      var getlink = $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").attr("href");
      // load contents of page at link into link
      $("a.blog-pager-newer-link").load(getlink + " #this-post-title"); // the space is important too
});
```